# Set the range of year in Materialize Calendar

Tags: javascript, materialize

How to set the year using Materialize calendar? I'm aiming to have a range from 1990 up to current year.

This is the code I'm using

```
function bindDatePicker(){
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
     selectMonths: true,
     selectYears: 50, 
     format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
 });
}
```

The range it showing is 1991 to 2041. How to set it to 1990 to 2016(curyear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function bindDatePicker(){
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: 50, 
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    min: new Date(1990,1,1),
    max: true  // `true` sets it to today. `false` removes any limits.
    });
}
```